# I want to smooth hard edges without effecting other in close proximity

Tags: edit-mode, edges

I want to smooth the edges in the red circle but I also want to keep the blue edge rough. I also want to smooth the blue edge along the horizontal line so the sharp cuts between the edges disappear.

[image]

Comment: Thank you that solved it, and can I somehow mark this question as solved?

Comment: Either a mod has to mark it as closed/duplicate, or you can answer you own question with the solution that worked for you

Comment: Okay, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marking the hard edges as *Creases* solved the problem.